# How can I Calculate the Average of the Array List

Tags: arrays, vb.net, average

Ok I need to get size of the array and the array inputs through a msgbox and display the array list in a list box and then get the average of the array list. here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    Dim i, size As Integer
    size = Val(InputBox("Please enter array size"))

    Dim sequence(size) As Integer

    'get array values
    i = 0
    Do While i < size
        sequence(i) = Val(InputBox("Please enter element of array"))
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    i = 0
    Do While i < size
        lstoutArray.Items.Add(sequence(i))
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you had an array with the numbers 1 and 3, what would be the average? How did you work it out? Now try that in code.

Answer (score 2):

While something like this will work:

```
    Dim lstoutArray As New ArrayList
    Dim lstoutCount As Double = 0
    Dim size As Double
    size = Val(InputBox("Please enter array size"))
    For i = 1 To size
        lstoutArray.Add(Val(InputBox("Please enter element of array")))
        lstoutCount += DirectCast(lstoutArray(lstoutArray.Count - 1), Double)
    Next
    Dim lstoutAverage As Double = lstoutCount / lstoutArray.Count
```

You can see from this example that one of the main drawbacks to using an arraylist, is that it isn't strongly typed.  Therefore to use the values in the arraylist you have to cast them as the type you need.

A List(Of) is much easier to use as it's strongly typed already and has the `Average` extension:

```
    Dim lstoutArray As New List(Of Double)
    Dim size As Double
    size = Val(InputBox("Please enter array size"))
    For i = 1 To size
        lstoutArray.Add(Val(InputBox("Please enter element of array")))
    Next
    Dim lstoutAverage = lstoutArray.Average
```